# How to bind an image loaded from disk in a TableView's ViewCell?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Here's what I'm doing:

I set a **placeholder image** as my ViewCell's subclass Image.

Then, **load an Image from disk** to **replace the placeholder**.

This works fine with the placeholder, however, after **setting the image from disk** (displaying correctly), if I **scroll out of view and then come back** I get this error:

```
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Stream has been closed'.
```

The StackTrace:

```
at System.IO.FileStream.Read (System.Byte[] array, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count) [0x0000d] in <d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0 
at Android.Runtime.InputStreamAdapter.Read (System.Byte[] bytes, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 length) [0x00006] in <33e6e739ac344166b157e323586f11a1>:0 
at Java.IO.InputStream.n_Read_arrayBII (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_b, System.Int32 off, System.Int32 len) [0x00019] in <33e6e739ac344166b157e323586f11a1>:0 
at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:c31b04e7-d4e0-4108-9aaf-784714d6a934 (intptr,intptr,intptr,int,int)
```

My ViewModel:

```
ImageSource profilePhoto = ImageSource.FromFile(FileNames.ProfilePlaceholderPNG);
public ImageSource ProfilePhoto
{
    get { return profilePhoto; }
    set {  profilePhoto = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}


public async Task LoadProfilePhoto()
{
    // Set placeholder first
    ProfilePhoto = ImageSource.FromFile(FileNames.ProfilePlaceholderPNG);

    // Attemp to load existing photo
    var photo = await Storage.Current.GetPhoto(FileNames.ProfilePictureJPG);
    if (photo != null)
    {
        ProfilePhoto = photo;
    }

}
```

Page.xaml.cs

```
private async Task SetTableView()
{

    var profileCell = new UserProfileCell();
    profileCell.Photo.BindingContext = viewModel;
    profileCell.Photo.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding("ProfilePhoto", BindingMode.OneWay));

    var tableSections = new List<TableSection>();

    tableSections.Add(new TableSection()
    {
        profileCell
    });

    Content = new TableView
    {
        HasUnevenRows = true,
        Intent = TableIntent.Menu,
        Root = new TableRoot()
        {
            tableSections
        }

    };

    await viewModel.LoadProfilePhoto();

}
```

The code to read the photo from disk:

```
public async Task<ImageSource> GetPhoto(string fileName)
{
    var localStorage = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
    var folderExists = await localStorage.CheckExistsAsync(PhotosFolder);

    if (!folderExists.Equals(ExistenceCheckResult.FolderExists))
        return null;

    var localStorageFolder = await localStorage.GetFolderAsync(PhotosFolder);
    var fileExists = await localStorageFolder.CheckExistsAsync(fileName);

    if (!fileExists.Equals(ExistenceCheckResult.FileExists))
        return null;

    IFile file = await localStorageFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);

    if (file == null)
        return null;

    var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccess.Read);
    var imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
    return imageSource;

}
```

Right now it's only happening in Android. I had this issue with iOS, but after using a placeholder the problem went away.

Now it **only happens in Android**. I'm using Xamarin.Forms.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I was able to gather, **Xamarin will attempt to dispose streams that are no longer in use**.

In order to work around this, as suggested [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22160/imagesource-fromstream-with-caching)

I modified the above code from *GetPhoto* to *GetPhotoBytes*:

```
public async Task<byte[]> GetPhotoBytes(string fileName)
{
    var localStorage = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
    var folderExists = await localStorage.CheckExistsAsync(PhotosFolder);

    if (!folderExists.Equals(ExistenceCheckResult.FolderExists))
    {
        return null;
    }

    var localStorageFolder = await localStorage.GetFolderAsync(PhotosFolder);
    var fileExists = await localStorageFolder.CheckExistsAsync(fileName);

    if (!fileExists.Equals(ExistenceCheckResult.FileExists))
    {
        return null;
    }

    IFile file = await localStorageFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);

    if (file == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccess.Read);

    byte[] bytes = null;
    using (var memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        stream.Dispose();
        bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    return bytes;

}
```

And the LoadProfilePhoto, now builds a stream from the bytes:

```
public async Task LoadProfilePhoto()
{
    // Set placeholder first
    ProfilePhoto = ImageSource.FromFile(FileNames.ProfilePlaceholderPNG);

    // Attemp to load existing photo
    var photoBytes = await Storage.Current.GetPhotoBytes(FileNames.ProfilePictureJPG);
    if (photoBytes != null)
    {
        var photo = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new System.IO.MemoryStream(photoBytes));
        if (photo != null)
        {
            ProfilePhoto = photo;
        }

    }

}
```

Now instead of using the stream from the file, I create a new from the Photo bytes. I have yet to understand why this stream isn't also disposed. However, for now, it seems to be working correctly.